# Handle Keyerror and show result anyway in pymongo and html

Tags: python, pymongo, keyerror

I'm trying to figure out how to print a result without keys, the database is going to be variable

I'm using the following dataset :

```
 "pet" : dog 
 "d" : {
    "city" : "Highland",
    "region_code" : "CA",
    "area_code" : 909,
    "time_zone" : "America/Los_Angeles",
    "dma_code" : 803,
    "metro_code" : "Los Angeles, CA",
    "country_code3" : "USA",
    "latitude" : 34.1359,
    "postal_code" : "92346",
    "longitude" : -117.1553,
    "country_code" : "US",
    "country_name" : "United States",
    "continent" : "NA"
},
```

I'm using the following to print the coutry name value

```
<td><a class="button6" >{{campo['pet']}}</a></td>
<td><a class="button6" >{{campo['d']['country_name']}}</a></td>
```

And works fine, print the country and the pet value, but the problem comes when there is no "d" value in the database, raises a Keyerror.

I need help about how to print the page with just the pet value when there is no "d" key

If you use the following

```
<td><a class="button6" >{{campo['d']}}</a></td>
```

The result prints fine even if "d" is empty, but doesn't works because i need the country name value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a `KeyError` using python's [built-in `get()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get) that operates on dictionaries. `get()` allows you to specify a default value, so you can do:

```
campo.get('d', {}).get('country_name')
```

to safely retrieve subkeys of `compo['d']`

Comment: Hello , works like charm!! appreciate your help, have a nice day .

Comment: But i'm having another error now, for example when there is no d value at all, raises AttributError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: If you use the syntax I suggested you shouldn't get that error.

Comment: Hello I'm using the syntax you provided and works well until i query a result empty "d" in the database, the "d" exist but is empty with Null , I'm  having the attribute error just because that, i think there is a way to circunvent that with some ==None or something like that .  Thanks for the help .

Comment: if you use get you can never get a KeyError. From the link I listed: get(key[, default]) Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, *so that this method never raises a KeyError*

Comment: Hello Agree with you , but I'm not having KeyError this time, , this time is AttributeError which a different thing,  Attribute error is because "d" is Null in database, that's what I'm looking to fix now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You'll have to raise that as a different question with all the details.